# Avoid showing empty page after unsuccessful authentication

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, spnego

*[CentOS 5.3, glassfish 3.1.1, jdk1.6.30 64bit, spnego R7]*

I defined a SPNEGO filter to authenticate users against AD using Kerberos (basic mode). If a user gives proper credencials, page content is sent to user. But if the authentication is not successful, an empty page with 401 error is returned to client. I have a page for 401 error defined in web.xml.

My question is: how to send to a user any content if SPNEGO authentication (==SPNEGO filter) fails? Do I have to define some SPNEGO parameter? Or should I add another filter to add the 'failed to log in' content if previous filter return nothing?

Comment: Kerberos is not about challenging the user with u/p but to exchange tickets. You filter is broken by design.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error-page setting in your web.xml should do what you want but SPNEGO should send a 403 (Login failed) instead of a 401 (Unauthorized). I have a similar environment but SPNEGO returns status code 403 which is mapped in my web.xml like this:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/access-forbidden.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```